# The iTunes currently-playing track is blank; how do I get it back?

Tags: itunes

I'm using iTunes 11.1.2 on the Mac. The top center of iTunes has an area that normally shows the currently-playing track (title, artist, album, etc.) with the track time slider. (Apparently this is called the "scrubber".)

After a recent Software Update, that area is now empty; it just has the Apple logo. I can't find any way to make the track data and time slider appear again (clicking and right-clicking does nothing, the View menu doesn't have an option for this, etc.).

How can I get this to reappear?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a lot of people are seeing this problem. Poster "musicelect" on [this Apple discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5468673?start=15&tstart=0) at least provided a work-around:

1. Close the main iTunes window with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
2. Then reopen it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>